# Recover plane from homography

Tags: opencv, normals, homography, plane

I have used openCV to calculate the homography relating to views of the same plane by using features and matching them. Is there any way to recover the plane itsself or the plane normal from this homography? (I am looking for an equation where H is the input and the normal n is the output.)

Comment: I am afraid this is more like a linear algebra question. You should find the plane equation given the initial plane and transformation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the calibration of the cameras, you can extract the normal of the plane, but not the distance to the plane (i.e. the transformation that you obtain is up to scale), as [Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography). I don't know any implementation to do it, but here you are a couple of papers that deal with that problem (I warn you it is not straightforward): [Faugeras & Lustman 1988](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/56/98/PDF/RR-0856.pdf), [Vargas & Malis 2005](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224627611_Visual_servoing_based_on_an_analytical_homography_decomposition).

You can recover the real translation of the transformation (i.e. the distance to the plane) if you have at least a real distance between two points on the plane. If that is the case, the easiest way to go with OpenCV is to first calculate the homography, then obtain four points on the plane with their 2D coordinates and the real 3D ones (you should be able to obtain them if you have a real measurement on the plane), and using PnP finally. PnP will give you a real transformation.

Comment: I am not actually interested in the distance to the plane. I want to rectify the image with respect to the plane (so the camera position is directly orthogonal to the plane).

Answer (score 0):

Rectifying an image is defined as making epipolar lines horizontal and lying in the same row in both images. From your description I get that you simply want to warp the plane such that it is parallel to the camera sensor or the image plane. This has nothing to do with rectification  - I’d rather call it an obtaining a bird’s-eye view or a top view.

I see the source of confusion though. Rectification of images usually involves multiplication of each image with a homography matrix. In your case though each point in sensor plane b:
Xb = Hab * Xa = (Hb * Ha^-1) * Xa, where Ha is homography from the plane in the world to the sensor a; Ha and intrinsic camera matrix will give you a plane orientation but I don’t see an easy way to decompose Hab into Ha and Hb.

A classic (and hard) way is to find a Fundamental matrix, restore the Essential matrix from it, decompose the Essential matrix into camera rotation and translation (up to scale), rectify both images, perform a dense stereo, then fit a plane equation into 3d points you reconstruct.

If you interested in the ground plane and you operate an embedded device though, you don’t even need two frames - a top view can be easily recovered from a single photo, camera elevation from the ground (H) and a gyroscope (or orientation vector) readings. A simple diagram below explains the process in 2D case: first picture shows how to restore Z (depth) coordinate to every point on the ground plane; the second picture shows a plot of the top view with vertical axis being z and horizontal axis x = (img.col-w/2)*Z/focal; Here is img.col is image column, w - image width, and focal is camera focal length. Note that a camera frustum looks like a trapezoid in a birds eye view.

[image: single image + gyroscope = depth]